# Нужен ли delete[] при использовании new c умным указателем типа auto

Tags: c++, c++11

Вопрос касается C++11, использования `auto` в подобной структуре:

```
auto array = new int[20];
```

Нужно ли в данном случае вызывать `delete []` для array, или деструктор умного указателя о нем позаботится сам?

По крайней мере данный код работает (вместо типа `int` я использовал структуру).

Comment: Думаю, здесь `auto` посто лишнее, даже буковок по сравнению с `int*` не экономит...  `auto` хорош там, где сокращает пару десятков символов кода, всякие итераторы от контейнеров, например.

Comment: @Alex Titov: Назначение `auto` - реализация принципа Do Not Repeat Yourself (DRY) в коде, т.е. избежание ненужного повторения имен типов. А экономит это буковки или нет - значения не имеет. В терминах "экономии" можно думать об этом так: если завтра надо будет исправить `int` на `long`, то в варианте с `auto` исправлять надо будет только правую часть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае `auto` - указатель, так что ни о каком умном указателе речь не идет.

Там, где вы использовали структуры - вряд ли у вас вызывались деструкторы.

Вот, чтоб [убедиться](https://ideone.com/KaAIKC):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test()   { cout << "Test()\n"; }
    ~Test()  { cout << "~Test()\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    auto t = new Test[5];
}
```

Вызываются только конструкторы, так что имеем обычную утечку памяти :)

Comment: Получается, нужно так: `auto t = std::make_unique<Test[]>(5);`
Тогда деструктор срабатывает

Comment: @GenrixStraus `make_unique` был добавлен в C++14.

Comment: Да, конечно - так `auto` будет выведен из возвращаемого типа `make_unique` и `t` в этом случае будет умным указателем.

Answer (score 2):

Никакого отношения к "умным указателям" данный `auto` не имеет. В данном случае вы получите обычный "голый" указатель, у которого нет никакого деструктора. Освобождение памяти через `delete[]` так же необходимо, как и обычно, и это - ваша задача.